# No response from setOnMapLongClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, onclicklistener

Android Studio 3.0.1. Google maps appCompat mode.

I am trying to toggle the ActionBar (Menu) on or off to display more of the map but the code below is not working; in fact the map does not even appear. What is wrong please?

```
 ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();  
 .
 .
 map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long CLICK",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ab.isShowing()) {
                ab.hide();
            } else {
                ab.show();
            }
          }
    });
```

I cannot get a response from the above when trying a long tap to hide/show the menu bar. 
There is also a *setOnMapClickListener* after this which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 getActionBar().isShowing()
```

Fore more detail [reference:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#isShowing())

Comment: Exactly the same as before. Nothing. There is no popup from Toast which indicates the event is not being trapped?

Answer (score 0):

Please upload your xml file because maybe some layout overlap your google map and it will not allow you to click on google map.